# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal character in authority at index 7 while making https request

Tags: java, android, android-emulator, wampserver

While making http request to my local wamp server from android emulator I got above error.

```
// testing on Emulator:
private static final String LOGIN_URL="http:// 10.0.2.2:80/webservice/login.php";

//request:
JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(LOGIN_URL, "POST", params);
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You have a space at index 7 of your string `LOGIN_URL` and it is causing the exception. It should be like this.

```
LOGIN_URL = "http://10.0.2.2:80/webservice/login.php"
```

Comment: I had a new line character and after i deleted "\n" it worked fine.

Answer (score 4):

I found the answer:
After googling for couple of hours I found that this kind of error occur due to
problem in url
I had extra space in my URL which I removed and I got everything working

```
    // testing on Emulator:
    private static final String LOGIN_URL = "http://10.0.2.2:80/webservice/login.php";
```

Comment: Consider marking one of the questions as accepted to prevent the SO bot keeping the question up in the top of the list and in the "Unanswered" section. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

Answer (score 1):

For me it was a new line character at the end of the url String. It wasn't really visible to the naked eye but I caught it with Vi. Pretty dumb error message, not at all helpful.